# Escape & character in string

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I want to set value appconfig key,but value contains & character.I tried double && like this "8L&&L26X0s8@P" but dont working.Can you help me please?

```
 <add key="SAP_PASS" value="8L&L26X0s8@P"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As `app.config` is `xml` file, use `XML` entities for this.

Specifically `&` is coded as `&amp;` (including the semicolon) in `XML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape any character using Regex.Escape(string)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `&amp` ? This is the usual escape