# Escape character on & c# textbox open xml

Tags: c#

I have a string variable which contains an & character. This string appears on the web page in a text box. This value is used throughout my web application. I am trying to merge documents using open XML:

ASPX code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mergeFiles[0], true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + i;
    AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(mergeFiles[i], FileMode.Open))
    {
        chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
     }

    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
    //new page, if you like it...
    mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
    mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().Last());
    mainPart.Document.Save();
    myDoc.Close();
    System.IO.File.Copy(mergeFiles[0], outputFileName, true);
```

it is failing on this bit:

```
mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
```

with the below error:

An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 4312.

I know the issue is with the & character because when I removed this character on the textbox the page continues to run fine without the above error.

I tried to replace & with the string 'and' and this also worked fine. However, I really need the string value to have the '&'.

Code to set the textbox value:

```
string name = EachApplicantXML.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText;

                //if (name.Contains("&"))
                //{
                //    name = name.Replace("&", "\\&");
                //}

                nametextbox.Value = name;
```

Example: name variable = 'A & B Ltd'

Can someone advise how I can do this please?

Comment: Have you tried `&amp;`?

Comment: It's not clear where you're using textbox at all - I don't see it in your first piece of code. Ideally you shouldn't start doing any escaping yourself. That's what the XML libraries should be doing. If you can clarify exactly what's going on, and ideally reproduce it in a [mcve] (a console app would be best for simplicity), it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: The textbox is on the front end for the user to input values or it retrieves an XML tag which includes the '&' in it. This is the line: EachApplicantXML.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText; which populates the textbox with this code:  nametextbox.Value = name;

Comment: But where does that fir into the first part of the code? That's what's entirely unclear. Again, a [mcve] would make it *much* easier to help you.

Comment: Have you tried using `Regex.Escape(value1)` from `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `&` in the string with the escape character `&amp;`. Similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061018/escape-character-in-string).

Comment: The problem with this is the textbox shows as:

A &amp; B

when i want it to show as A & B to the user

Comment: I have managed to fix it by creating an extra variable, one that replaces & with &amp and the other which takes the textbox value & and this is now working. Sorry if i had not explained clear